# Set value for YUI Menu Button

Tags: yui

I'm trying to set the assigned value to a YUI Menu Button in order to use values from previous operations.

Something like remembering previous choices.

For label I already know that I can change it with:
 `button.set("label", "my label")`

unfortunatelly I cannot change the value using:  `button.set("value", "my value")`

Any ideia on how can I do this?

Other way would be to force a selection, but I have no ideia on how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out that you can use:

`var menu = button.getMenu();
var item = menu.getItem(index);
button.set("selectedMenuItem", item);`

all that is left for me now is finding the needed index

Comment: Warning: do not forget to set the button with "lazyloadmenu: false"